# How do I set ignore backspace for hotstrings?

Tags: autohotkey

I keep getting unwanted hotstrings, like for example I have `mw` making `㎽` but if I type an <kbd>m</kbd> by mistake, and then erase it with <kbd>BackSpace</kbd>, and then type a <kbd>w</kbd> AHK kicks in, even though there was a <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> — how do I set it so that <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> will interrupt a hotstring?

Answer (score 1):

This is unusual behaviour for AutoHotKey. One of my many hotstrings is `:*:ahk::AutoHotKey` if I press `ah`<kbd>BackSpace</kbd>`k`<kbd>Space</kbd> I get `ak` as expected and *not*, as in your case `AutoHotKey`.

Could you show the initial lines and the hotstrings of the script and tell us wich OS and which AutoHotKey version you are using?

I do run AutoHotKey_L, but in the past I ran AutoHotKey and I never ran into your behaviour.

Comment: It was because I had remapped backspace functionality to the Caps Lock key. I made a thread about it on the AutoHotKey forums if you would like to have a look. I still have a problem, even after using #inputLevel. I have supplied the requested information in that thread, for what it's worth.

Comment: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/89797-how-do-i-set-ignore-backspace-for-hotstrings/

Comment: Basically, I had Caps Lock and backspace swapped. Somehow this is only possible without #InpetLevels, it would seem. Anyway, it was a blessing in disguise, because I actually prefer having two backspace keys! I am posting the link for you in any case, because this is perhaps a bug.